# Is there a way to automatically reduce the rating of a song by X stars when you skip that song?

Tags: itunes, automation

For example, to reduce a song's rating by half a star when you skip it (and/or increase it by half when you don't?).

Not sure if this would involve creating a new application or if somehow there's an easy way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes application (iOS **or** OS X) alone does not have the built-in function or enablable feature for automatically reducing the rating of the songs because you skipped it.

I would say this is because there could be multiple reasons for skipping a song, not all of them being because you didn't like it.

I don't think that an Automator script can handle this task, either.